# Applying mean value theorem 1 to expectation.

Tags: probability, integration

I would like to prove that for an arbitrary real random variable $X$ defined on some continuous and closed interval $S$, if functions $h(x)$ and $g(x)$ are bounded, continuous and non-zero over $S$, we can find some $x_0 \in S$ such that
$$
\frac{\mathbb{E}[h(X)]}{\mathbb{E}[g(X)]} = \frac{h(x_0)}{g(x_0)}
$$
$X$ can be either continuous or discrete.

My proof is
$$
\frac{\mathbb{E}[h(X)]}{\mathbb{E}[g(X)]} = \frac{\int_S h(x) d F_X(x)}{\int_S g(x) d F_X(x)} = \frac{\int_S \frac{h(x)}{g(x)} g(x) d F_X(x)}{\int_S g(x) d F_X(x)} = \frac{\frac{h(x_0)}{g(x_0)} \int_S  g(x) d F_X(x)}{\int_S g(x) d F_X(x)} = \frac{h(x_0)}{g(x_0)}
$$
because $h(x)/g(x)$ is continuous on $S$. Is there anything I am missing? Not an expert in probability, so I am wondering if there is any formal theorem for this result.

Comment: This mean value theorem only holds if h/g does not change sign on S

Comment: I think that your proof is correct. $h/g$ is continuous on $S$ so the (first) MVT for integrals holds. BTW, $h/g$ does not change sign (because both $f$ and $g$ preserve the sign by continuity ) but I do not think that is relevant.